# Python timezone issue?

Tags: python, datetime

im having troubles with parsing a feed and getting the time.  i am using dateutil.parser

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

print updated, parse(updated ), parse( updated ).utcoffset()
```

this should be a time in cali, output

```
2010-05-20T11:00:00.000-07:00 2010-05-20 11:00:00.000000-07:00 -1 day, 17:00:00
```

why is the offset -1 day 17 hours?

this is causing me issues when i try to do things with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Minus 7 hours" is equal to "minus 1 day, plus 17 hours". So probably the time zone offset is correct and just displayed in a weird way.